# Floating inner div in parent

Tags: css, html

#### Please, fill the form to confirm your identity:

...

What I get:
[alt text http://uppix.net/5/1/6/342256fb5ed24938b5d8bed634772.jpg](http://uppix.net/5/1/6/342256fb5ed24938b5d8bed634772.jpg)

How can I make inner(red) div floating top?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. What do you mean? What do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: @cletus I've updated image and question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first, make sure you reset all element's margins (using a [reset css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) for example), if it stills doesn't work you can try `margin-top: -X`

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the 'please, fill the form to confirm your identity' text?

If so, by the looks of the code you have supplied it may by a margin issue from one of the elements within the modalBox. ensure the 'please, ...' div has a margin-top:0;

that may fix it.